# Attaching a div to a path of a moving image and make it keep its relative position when resizing the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a path for an image to move along when scrolling and I want text boxes to be placed next to the extremes of the curves. I can move these boxes to a specific positions however the problem I have then is that when people with different screens sizes or when resizing the window the path moves but the text boxes not making them misaligned. Preferably I would also make these text boxes open when the image moves past the extremes but this is optional.

The code I created is provided below and I simply do not know how to continue from here. I am satisfied with the path the image moves along although if someone has advice for improvement this is more than welcome.

```js
var scrollY = 0;

var path = document.getElementById("path");
var car = document.getElementById("c");

document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
  positionBac();
});

function positionBac() {
  var maxScrollY = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
  var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
  var dist = pathLen * scrollY / maxScrollY;
  var pos = path.getPointAtLength(dist);
  var angle = calculateAngle(path, pathLen, dist, pos);

  car.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + pos.x + "," + pos.y + ") rotate(" + (rad2deg(angle) + 90) + ")");
}

function calculateAngle(path, pathLen, dist, pos) {
  if (dist + 1 <= pathLen) {
    var posAhead = path.getPointAtLength(dist + 1);
    return Math.atan2(posAhead.y - pos.y, posAhead.x - pos.x);
  } else {
    var posBehind = path.getPointAtLength(dist - 1);
    return Math.atan2(pos.y - posBehind.y, pos.x - posBehind.x);
  }
}

function rad2deg(rad) {
  return 180 * rad / Math.PI;
}

positionBac();
```

```css
.route {
  width: 90%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}

.svg {
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
}

.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: #98CC9B;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 200px;
}

.box:nth-child(odd) {
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-right: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="route">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 2500" id="svgRoute">
      <path id="path" d="M500 0 
      C500 100 1200 300 500 500 
      C500 500 -200 700 500 900
      C500 900 1200 1100 500 1300
      C500 1300 -200 1500 500 1700
      C500 1700 1200 1900 800 2100 
      C800 2100 400 2300 400 2500" 
      stroke-width="3px"  stroke="green" fill="none"/>
    <image id="c" x="-20" y="-70" width="40" height="70" xlink:href="nani.png"/>

 
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="box">this</div>
<div class="box">is</div>
<div class="box">an</div>
<div class="box">example</div>
<div class="box">Box</div>
```

I've tried to attach the divs to points at the curve so when you resize the window the boxes remain aligned. This simply doesn't work and I cannot seem to solve this issue.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Comment: How long would you want a text to remain visible? E.g. until the car reaches the next bend?

Comment: Have you tried showing the text when the car turns a corner (or, when it is about to if that is required)? You have its coordinates so can position the text accordingly.

Comment: The text should show up when the car turns the corner and it should remain visible after that. Although I have not worked at this yet since I would like to get the positioning of the text right before I start working on that.

Comment: I think the two are linked as you know when the car turns a corner, and where it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know when the car turns (the angle changes from less than 180 to more than 180 or vice versa) and we know its position in terms of the path.

So, we can work out what bend it is on (or near) and show the relevant text at the car's position - thus avoiding having to do any calculation of where a bend actually is.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="box bend0">this</div>
  <div class="box bend1">is</div>
  <div class="box bend2">an</div>
  <div class="box bend3">example</div>
  <div class="box bend4 ">Box</div>
  <!--<div class="box bend5 "></div><!-- there is a bend at the very end of the path -->-->
  <div class="container">
    <div id="route">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 2500" id="svgRoute">
      <path id="path" d="M500 0 
      C500 100 1200 300 500 500 
      C500 500 -200 700 500 900
      C500 900 1200 1100 500 1300
      C500 1300 -200 1500 500 1700
      C500 1700 1200 1900 800 2100 
      C800 2100 400 2300 400 2500" 
      stroke-width="3px"  stroke="green" fill="none"/>
    <image id="c" x="-20" y="-70" width="40" height="70" xlink:href="nani.png"/>

 
    </svg>
    </div>
    <script>
      bendsY = [500, 900, 1300, 1700, 2100, 2300];

      var scrollY = 0;

      var path = document.getElementById("path");
      var car = document.getElementById("c");
      let prevAngle = 0;
      let curAngle = 0;
      let bend = -1;
      let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
      const numBends = boxes.length;
      let prevY = 0;
      let curY = 0;
      let goingDown = true;

      document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        scrollY = window.pageYOffset;
        //event.preventDefault();
        //event.stopPropagation();
        positionBac();
      });

      function hideBoxes() {
        boxes.forEach(box => {
          box.style.opacity = 0;
        });
      }
      hideBoxes();

      function positionBac() {
        var maxScrollY = document.documentElement.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
        var pathLen = path.getTotalLength();
        var dist = pathLen * scrollY / maxScrollY;
        var pos = path.getPointAtLength(dist);
        var angle = calculateAngle(path, pathLen, dist, pos);


        function findBend() {
          for (let i = 0; i < numBends; i++) {
            if (pos.y <= bendsY[i]) {
              bend = i;
              break;
            }
          }
        }

        function showText() {
          findBend();
          hideBoxes();
          const el = document.querySelector('.box.bend' + bend);
          el.style.opacity = 1;
          el.style.top = (document.querySelector('image').getBoundingClientRect().y + scrollY) + 'px';
        }

        car.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + pos.x + "," + pos.y + ") rotate(" + (rad2deg(angle) + 90) + ")");

        prevAngle = curAngle;
        curAngle = rad2deg(angle) + 90;
        prevY = curY;
        curY = scrollY;
        if (curY <= .1) {
          bend = -1;
          goingDown = true;
        }
        if (curY > prevY) { //going down
          if (bend < (numBends - 1)) {
            if (atABend()) {
              if (!goingDown) {
                goingDown = true;
              } else if (bend < (numBends - 1)) {
                showText();
              }
            }
          }
        } else { //going up
          if (bend > -1) {
            if (atABend()) {
              if (goingDown) {
                goingDown = false;
              } else if (bend > 0) {
                showText();
              }
            }
          }
        }

      }

      function atABend() {
        return (prevAngle < 180 && curAngle >= 180) || (prevAngle > 180 && curAngle <= 180);
      }

      function calculateAngle(path, pathLen, dist, pos) {
        if (dist + 1 <= pathLen) {
          var posAhead = path.getPointAtLength(dist + 1);
          return Math.atan2(posAhead.y - pos.y, posAhead.x - pos.x);
        } else {
          var posBehind = path.getPointAtLength(dist - 1);
          return Math.atan2(pos.y - posBehind.y, pos.x - posBehind.x);
        }
      }

      function rad2deg(rad) {
        return 180 * rad / Math.PI;
      }

      function reset() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        scrollY = 0;
        positionBac();
      }
      window.onresize = reset;
      positionBac();
    </script>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
      }
      
      .route {
        width: 90%;
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
      }
      
      .svg {
        width: 90%;
        height: auto;
      }
      
      .box {
        width: 15%;
        aspect-ratio: 3 / 2;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        margin-top: 0px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        background: #98CC9B;
        border-radius: 6px;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
      }
      
      .box:nth-child(odd) {
        right: 0;
      }
      
      .box:nth-child(even) {
        left: 0;
      }
    </style>
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913450/attaching-a-div-to-a-path-of-a-moving-image-and-make-it-keep-its-relative-positi
</body>

</html>
```